# Combinate path and normal animation?

Tags: animation, path

I have a short question. I want to animate a man, who walks through the room, then takes a chair and sits down. 
I want to make a walk cycle and then a follow path animation for the walking part. When the man reaches the chair, can I continue to animate the man normally? Like "out" of the path I mean?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a parent>"follow path" (say 100 frames) to animate the first part, the "walk", then just insert keyframes for the second part of the animation at the end of the first part (say starting at frame 101).

In a much simplified example,

this could be the path animation (1-100)

[image]

and this the keyframe after (101-200)

[image]

and this would be the result

[image]

Comment: thanks, i'm not sure if that's the technique i'm looking for but i'll give it a try :)

Comment: Will he need to keyframer parenting at the end?